# C# List, Array List, Dictionary, Hash Table and ICollection

Tags: c#, arrays

I am a newbie in C#. I've reached to the lesson so far with regards to the "collections" topic. Now I am very confused with how C# implements collection because I found these (List, Array LIst, Dictionary, Hash Table and ICollection) for implementing / declaring an array (key-value pair arrays - if in PHP) collection. I am a PHP developer starting to learn C# and if anyone can tell me how, when and when not to use the following collection declaration in C# since in PHP, there is no variable type restriction when adding objects to array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: None of the collections you mention (List, Array LIst, Dictionary, Hash Table and ICollection) are actually arrays. I don't know enough about coming from PHP to clarify your confusion.

Comment: @spender - I believe all arrays in PHP are not strongly typed, and thus the equivalent to `List<object>` - you can store any combination of things in them.

Comment: @Bobson: "An array in PHP is actually an ordered map." [source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) The problem with this is that php uses `array` for everything. Therefore many php developers that don't know the real name of the data structure they want to use. This leads to confusion when asking questions or moving to other languages.

Comment: @unholysampler - Ah, so it's more `Dictionary<object, object>`.  Ugh.  Reminds me why I gave up PHP.

Comment: @spender There is array in the abstract computer science sense, and then there is `Array` as in the C# type.  A List/ArrayList are arrays, in the broader computer science sense, and a dictionary or hashtable is an associative array (which is a type of array), in the broader computer science sense.  In PHP, all of these collections use a single language "type", called an array.

Answer (score 1):

`List` tends to be the most robust I've found. I very rarely use ArrayList or Dictionary, but that's just me.

Comment: it really depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yup. I've found just from whatever I'm working on that List meets about 95% of my needs.

Comment: I actually use `Dictionary` as much as `List`, if not more.  It very much varies depending on how you do things.

Comment: Please use List<T> instead of List, ArrayList. There is also an Dictionary<T>. You won't need to unbox values manually which will result in a faster program execution.

Comment: @UNeverNo - I didn't actually realize there were non-generic versions of them, to tell you the truth...